ESP protocol block size and alignment size requirement
I am having a hard time understanding alignment requirement when using ESP protocol. RFC 4303 says

Note that the beginning of the next layer protocol header MUST be
aligned relative to the beginning of the ESP header as follows. For
IPv4, this alignment is a multiple of 4 bytes.  For IPv6, the
alignment is a multiple of 8 bytes.

1st question - If next protocol header (payload) needs to be aligned to 4 or 8 bytes then size of {ESP Header + IV (optional)} needs to be multiple of 4 or 8 bytes. Is this correct? What if IV of size 10 bytes is used? Should we add padding bytes after IV and before payload to satisfy the alignment requirement?
RFC 4303 also says that padding is required

If an encryption algorithm is employed that requires the plaintext to
be a multiple of some number of bytes, e.g., the block size of a block
cipher, the Padding field is used to fill the plaintext (consisting of
the Payload Data, Padding, Pad Length, and Next Header fields) to the
size required by the algorithm.
Padding also may be required, irrespective of encryption algorithm
requirements, to ensure that the resulting ciphertext terminates on a
4-byte boundary. Specifically, the Pad Length and Next Header fields
must be right aligned within a 4-byte word, as illustrated in the ESP
packet format figures above, to ensure that the ICV field (if present) is aligned
on a 4-byte boundary.

2nd Question - How to add padding to the payload so that block size requirement is satisfied as well the size of cipher text is multiple of 4 bytes?
Assume I will add 'x' padding bytes to satisfy the block size requirement. Next I will add 'y' bytes to satisfy the cipher text alignment to 4 byte boundary requirement. Doesn't adding 'y' bytes disturb the block size requirement done previously?
3rd Question - Is the requirement Cipher text size multiple of 4 same for IPv4 and IPv6?
